Did God change Sarai's name to Sarah as a random choice?
We read in Gen 17:1-5 (KJV):

And when Abram was ninety years old and nine, the Lord appeared to Abram, and said unto him, I am the Almighty God; walk before me,....Neither shall thy name any more be called Abram, but thy name shall be Abraham; for a father of many nations have I made thee.

We also read in Verse 15:

And God said unto Abraham, As for Sarai thy wife, thou shalt not call her name Sarai, but Sarah shall her name be.

We see God describing the reason and purpose of giving a new name to Abram .Verse 5 of Orthodox Jewish Bible goes:

" Neither shall thy shem any more be called Avram, but thy shem shall be Avraham; for Av hamon Goyim (Father of a multitude of Goyim) have I made thee ".

But, when it comes to the turn of Sarai, God does not elaborate what her new name Sarah means . Was the change a random choice from God's side ? What according to scholars , could be the reason for the change
?

I think it was to give her a new identity. Our names influence our destinies. So she was given that name for she was about to give rise to a nation of priests. A holy nation which will ultimately father the promised Messiah.

When God decrees that personal names should be changed, or states what an as-yet unconceived child is to be named at birth, there is never anything 'random' about those names! Consider what the addition of one single letter to both names did.
In both cases, God added the fifth letter of the Hebrew alphabet (= H). For Abram, God put it in to give Abraham. Whereas Abram meant "exalted father", Abraham meant "father of a multitude".
With his wife, God also added the fifth letter of the Hebrew alphabet (= H) to make is Sarah. Sarai meant "princely", whereas Sarai meant "princess". In that case, her female status was elevated. She, in her person, was being honoured as becoming a mother, aged 90! Prior to then, her inability to bear children would have been an awful thing to endure. No longer!
That is why the way in which God changed her name was deliberate, done in advance of her conceiving by Abraham. And the child conceived was also given a name (in advance) by God. A male child would be born, and called Isaac, which means 'laughter'. And, indeed, what laughter of joy there was when Sarah successfully gave birth to her one and only child, when she was aged 90.
Back then, the Hebrew people attached great significance to names, for they all had meanings. Very much so was this with the case of God's commands regarding the names Abraham, Sarah, and Isaac.
Further, the extra Hebrew letter added, being the fifth letter of the Hebrew alphabet, represents grace. This is where gematria comes in to play (the addition of the numerical value of letters). Divine grace adds gifts and blessing to the work of God's hands, and those two people experienced that when God added the fifth letter to their existing names.
[Points taken from The Companion Study Bible, notes and Appendix 10.]

Thanks, Anne. Going by the OJB , ' ham' is the short form of 'hamon' meaning  'of a multitude ' .  It it possible that only  the  consonant ' h' was involved in the change?

@KadalikattJosephSibichan  I do not know. A Hebrew scholar would best answer that. But certainly, 'a multitude' resulted after both names were changed by God.

Thanks, Anne.  I hope the pun  in ' multitude' is intended.

Most commentaries address this question.  Here is just one from the Pupit commentary:

Verse 15. - And God said unto Abraham, As for Sarai thy wife, - who,
not having hitherto been mentioned in any of the promises, is now
expressly taken into covenant, and accordingly receives a new name
(cf. Ver. 5; Genesis 32:28; Revelation 3:12) - thou shalt not call her
name Sarai, - "my princess" (Gesenius); "princely, noble" (Ikenins,
Rosenmüller, Keil, Delitzsch); "the heroine" (Knobel); "strife,
contention" (Ewald, Murphy), with special reference to her struggle
against sterility. (Kalisch) - but Sarah "princess" (Gesenius), the
meaning being that, whereas formerly she was Abram's princess only,
she was henceforth to be recognized as a princess generally, i.e. as
the mother of the Church (Jerome, Augustine), or as princess to the
Lord, the letter A being taken from the name Jehovah, as in the change
of Abram into Abraham (the Rabbis); though Ikenius and Rosenmüller
derive from an Arabic root, sara, to have a numerous progeny - shall
her name be. Genesis 17:15

